# Image Processing - Demosaicing CFA image using color interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I am studying how to mosaic images with CFA(Color Filter Array) like the image below.

[image]

And how to demosaic the CFA mosaic images with many interpolation methods. So I could make 4 different mosaic images with CFAs. The CFA patterns that I used are in the image below.

[image]

But I'm not sure how to do color interpolation with CFA mosaic images like below. Can anybody tell me how to do this? or Give me some clues?
[image]

I want to try nearest neighbor interpolation, bilinear interpolation and bicubic interpolation for demosaicing.

I'm using opencv, numpy, and matplotlib packages now.

I tried to demosaic with opencv's resize method. Because there is I interpolation parameter. But I think it doesn't do interpolation because it gave me results same as source image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

cfa0 = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Resources/cfa0.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cfa1 = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Resources/cfa1.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cfa2 = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Resources/cfa2.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cfa3 = cv2.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Resources/cfa3.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

(h,w) = cfa0.shape[0:2]
linear = cv2.resize(cfa0,(w,h),interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
nearest = cv2.resize(cfa0,(w,h),interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST_EXACT)
cubic = cv2.resize(cfa0,(w,h),interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

fig = plt.figure(dpi=300)
fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
# showing image
plt.imshow(cfa0)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("First")
  
# Adds a subplot at the 2nd position
fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
# showing image
plt.imshow(linear)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("linear")
cv2.imwrite('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Resources/linear.png',linear)
  
# Adds a subplot at the 3rd position
fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
# showing image
plt.imshow(nearest)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("nearest")
cv2.imwrite('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Resources/nearest.png',nearest)
  
# Adds a subplot at the 4th position
fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4) 
# showing image
plt.imshow(cubic)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("cubic")
# Combine all the operations and display
cv2.imwrite('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Resources/cubic.png',cubic)
plt.show()
```

Is there a way that I can get color-interpolated images?

Comment: You forgot to say what's wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: @MarkRansom There is nothing wrong with the code I posted. I posted code because I wanted to show what image arrays I haf as result. And I know it has color information but I have no clue how to do color interpolation for demosacing images. I treid search scipy interp1d method I'm not sure how to do color interpolation with it.

Comment: @Junhyun Ahn could you share your CFA mosaic images?